# Spring Security Custom Login Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been trying to add Spring Security Custom Login(Java Config) into my application, but a strange error keeps popping up.

I have gone through the [Creating a Custom Login Form tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/form.html) and it works just fine. I am not sure what is the issue with my application.

**Error**

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'login?error' is not a
>   valid redirect URL

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/about").permitAll();
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin","/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("login")
        .permitAll();
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginView() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute Login login) {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Just commenting the method `configure(HttpSecurity http)` removes the exception. I tried adding `RequestMapping` with value `login?error`, but it didn't help. What am I missing here?

[Link to complete stack trace](http://hastebin.com/ekerawituh.sm)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your are missing a slash.

This:

```java
.loginPage("login")
```

Should be:

```java
 .loginPage("/login")
```

Comment: Well, the slash is left out because my controller has a `RequestMapping` of "login" instead of "/login"

Comment: @ItachiUchiha `@RequestMapping` values should start with `/` too.